# is it possible to intercept the response to an HTTP OPTIONS preflight in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, cors

I'm trying to implement a simple interceptor that allows me to display a message along the lines of "cannot contact the server" in my Angular app. However as the API is on a different host I'm dealing with CORS pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests.

I've found that if the API is unavailable Chrome dev tools shows a `503` on the `OPTIONS` request but Angular's `$http` interceptor catches a `404` response to the subsequent `GET` request. I believe this is because the `OPTIONS` response did not contain the required CORS headers so the `GET` is actually never performed.

Is is possible to intercept the `OPTIONS` response? If all I see is a `404` I can't distinguish "server down" from "no such resource".

Comment: No, there is no way to intercept a preflight response from client-side JavaScript.  The browser is in completely control of this request.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was probably the case. It's frustrating if I can't at least see the HTTP status code. Leaves me powerless to handle error conditions in a useful way.

Comment: I'm in the exact same position... Can't find how to catch a backend failure client-side.

Comment: I'm in the same position too. I want to be able to show a 'server down' error message but can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: I am looking at the Angular source trying to figure out where the 404 is coming from but I see no special handling of pre-flight requests there so I can only assume it's the browser. I would think the correct code would be a 400. Does anyone know if this is discussed in the CORS spec at all?

Comment: Wow. what a bummer. Some back-end stacks make it very easy to auth REST routes globally, so that the OPTIONS route gets a `403`. Since the client can't read that, all it can see is the `0` of an aborted request, which is the same for server down, and some other cases. Disambiguation is difficult, and this should be an easy problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't intercept this request by design - the browser is "checking up" on you, making sure YOU should be allowed to make the request.

We've used three solutions to work around this:

- If the problem is that you're using a development environment like NodeJS, and your domain names aren't matching (that is, if you normally wouldn't need to deal with this in Production) you can use a proxy. The https://github.com/substack/bouncy[BounceJS NodeJS Module](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) is an easy to use option. Then your Web service request domain will match the domain your page is on, and the check won't be triggered. (You can also use tricks like this in Production, although it can be easily abused!)
- Also for temporary use, you can use something like Fiddler or Charles to manipulate the request by faking the required headers, or tell your browser not to check them (--disable-web-security in Chrome).
- If you have this problem in Production, you either need to legitimately fix it (adjust the Web service handler to add the required headers - there are only two), or find a way to make the request in a way that doesn't trigger the check. For instance, if you control both the source and target domains, you can put a script on the **target** that makes the requests to itself. Run this in an IFRAME, invisibly. Then you can use things like postMessage() to communicate back and forth. Large services like Facebook use "XHR bridges" like this for the same reason.